# Google apps / Google app engine relations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I've got a question concerning the two "products" Google provides : google apps (dedicated gmail, docs, calendar...) and google app engine (application in the cloud).

If I want to develop an application inside google apps, is it necessarily on google app engine ? Or can I develop a basic webapp with wathever i want (spring, grails, or anything else) ?

I understand google app engine since i've already develop on it, but google apps is more obscure.

Behind the question, i want to know if i can use something else than app engine to go on google apps, because app engine limitations are a kind of boring (file upload with blobstore is a mess : 1mb limit, upload with http...)

Comment: as far as I remember the one with the 1mb limit is maximum individual item size inside Memcache. Blobstore max is 2 GB.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use App Engine at all. See that the Google Apps Marketplace has tutorials for languages not even supported in App Engine: PHP, Ruby, .NET and Java (ok, this last one is supported ;-):

http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial.html

And by the way: blobstore upload limit is not 1MB, but 2 gigabytes.

Comment: maximum size of Blobstore data that can be read by the app with one API call => 1 megabyte

If I have files bigger than 1 mb, how to read them ?

Comment: @Jerome Are you trying to interact with a blob that's bigger than 1MB or just serve it? Serving a blob of any size up to 2GB is allowed, and easy. Think of the blobstore as the place to store large user-uploaded files (docs, pdfs, large images) rather than a place to store 2GB records for modifying in your app.

Comment: @Jerome That sounds like a separate question.